# get value if not null with ramda js

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

How i write the code as functional if i has the value like this

```
const data = {
name: null,
email: null,
username: 'johndoo'
}
```

in this case if i write the function that return the display name i just wrote `data.name || data.email || data.username`

I try to use ramda like

```
const getName = R.prop('name')
const getEmail = R.prop('email')
const getUsername = R.prop('username')
const getDisplayName = getName || getEmail || getUsername
```

but doesn't work, how to write it in ramdajs

Comment: My first question is *why* you want to rewrite this with Ramda?  While it could be done, I'm sure, what advantage do you expect to gain?

Comment: As @ScottSauyet said, what are you trying to accomplish? You shouldn't force to use Ramda nor any other library if not required.
If you just want to get the `displayUsername` in the specified order, that should be fine. Being that said, unless you need the other three variables, I would just do const `getDisplayName = R.prop('name') || R.prop('email') || R.prop('username')`

Comment: @R.DarioDuarte: That won't work, as the OP already noted.  `R.prop('name')` and the others are functions, so this is equivalent to `func1 || func2 || func3`, which will always return `func1`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a *logical or* [`R.either`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#either):

```
const getDisplayName = R.either(getName, R.either(getEmail, getUsername))
```

Or more compact with `R.reduce`:

```
const getDisplayName = R.reduce(R.either, R.isNil)([getName, getEmail, getUsername])
```

```js
const data = {
  name: null,
  email: null,
  username: 'johndoo'
}

const getName = R.prop('name')
const getEmail = R.prop('email')
const getUsername = R.prop('username')

const eitherList = R.reduce(R.either, R.isNil)

const getDisplayName = eitherList([getName, getEmail, getUsername])

console.log(getDisplayName(data))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```